# Getting error while trying to connect MS Access Database using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyodbc

I am trying to made connection with MS Access Database using following code but continuously I am getting error.

```
import pyodbc

conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver ={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="C:\Users\XYZ\Shopping_History.accdb;"')
csr = conn. cursor()
csr.execute('select * from Shopping_Details')
for row in csr.fetchall():
    print(row)
```

Error I am facing is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/XYZ/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/Database_Connection.py", line 3, in <module>
    conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver ={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};' r'DBQ="C:\Users\XYZ\Shopping_History.accdb;"')
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute (0)')

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Getting following output for the pyodbc.drivers()

```
>>> import pyodbc
>>> pyodbc.drivers()
['Driver da Microsoft para arquivos texto (*.txt; *.csv)', 'Driver do Microsoft Access (*.mdb)', 'Driver do Microsoft dBase (*.dbf)', 'Driver do Microsoft Excel(*.xls)', 'Driver do Microsoft Paradox (*.db )', 'Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)', 'Microsoft Access-Treiber (*.mdb)', 'Microsoft dBase Driver (*.dbf)', 'Microsoft dBase-Treiber (*.dbf)', 'Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)', 'Microsoft Excel-Treiber (*.xls)', 'Microsoft ODBC for Oracle', 'Microsoft Paradox Driver (*.db )', 'Microsoft Paradox-Treiber (*.db )', 'Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)', 'Microsoft Text-Treiber (*.txt; *.csv)', 'SQL Server', 'ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server']
>>>
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `conn = pyodbc.connect(r'Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\Users\XYZ\Shopping_History.accdb;')`

Comment: Still it is showing the same error.

Comment: Check the list returned by `pyodbc.drivers()` to see what drivers are available to your Python app.

Comment: Able to see Microsoft Access Driver is available. I have updated output of that in my main question

Comment: I am using office 365 64-bit version and Python 32-bit version. Does this make any difference? If yes, then is there any solution which can help to overcome this issue?

Comment: See [this entry in the pyodbc wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Connecting-to-Microsoft-Access). Note especially that `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)` and `Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb)` are totally separate drivers.